# How to interact with blockchain without any third party app

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I want to deploy a simple smart contract on `ETH` blockchain and want users to interact with the functions on the contract though my website without them having to download any dApp like METAMASK.

How can I achieve this whilst still maintaining the decentralized purpose for using the blockchain in the first place?


One option I am looking at is to generate addresses/accounts for all users using any web3js python or PHP library. Won't this approach defeat the whole purpose of using the blockchain for data integrity?


What other approaches exist for this usecase?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to deploy a simple smart contract on ETH blockchain and want users to interact with the functions on the contract though my website without them having to download any dApp like METAMASK.

You don't.

The point of a public blockchain is that users are in control of their wallet and their private keys. If there is no wallet integration and if you are simply doing transactions on the behalf of the user, there is no point to use a blockchain.